# Intel Atom N270/N280 processors - 32-bit or 64-bit OS Compatible?

Tags: cpu, 32-bit, atom

I have a netbook with either an Intel Atom N270 or N280 Processor. Curious to know whether 64-bit OS will run or is it just 32-bit compliant?

Answer (score 7):

Both Intel Atom N270 and N280 are 32-bit processors

Comment: Thanks! - I have tried to increase your reputation but mine is not high enough yet! :-(